# Can't change TCP/IPv4 settings on windows 10

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, vmware

As I am trying to change my wireless IPv4 or DNS IP address, everything goes well until I click OK.

The adapter window pops up this error: `"An unexpected condition occurred. Not all of your requested changes in settings could be made"`

[image: Picture of the error message]

Even when I restored Windows, disabled and re enabled the adapter, the problem was not solved.

Any help would be appreciated.

*Edit:* **I fixed that by resetting Windows 10. No other solution worked for me.**

Comment: If I recall correctly, I had similar issue in the past and "fixed" it by temporarily disabling/deleting virtual machine connection. Tho it could be for M$ VM, not vmware.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest drivers https://www.atheros-drivers.com/download-driver-for-Atheros-chipset-with-id-83-and-Windows10-64bit.html

Comment: I checked, I do have the latest version.

Comment: Do you have vmware installed on this machine?

Comment: Yeah vmware is installed, but its adapter is not present on the network adapters list. I tried to reinstall it but it didn't work. The virtual networks are not connected nither http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjr1Q.jpg

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP ended up resetting their OS. No way to recreate the problem. No clear idea of the solution. Lots of low quality comments being posted as "answers".

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the "Bridged" entry from VMWare's program called "Virtual Network Editor"

Comment: That didn't work too. I even tried to uninstall VMware but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
I solved the problem by opening a password secured Harddrive, which contained a Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails troubleshooting a network issue, you can always remove and re-add the network adapter.

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, select `Device Manager`.  Open up `Network Adapters` and right-click your network adapter and select `Uninstall`.  Since you said you have VMWare, I would uninstall those virtual adapters as well, as well as any other virtual adapters tied to the physical NIC.

Once that is done, reboot and let Windows redetect the NIC and install the drivers.  Once that is complete, you can re-setup the VMWare virtual NICs.

Comment: How to re-detect the NIC and install the drivers ? Because I did that but I couldn't be able to reinstall the driver (I have Acer Aspire E 15, I downloaded its driver from the official website and installed it but it didn't work). So I had to restore previous status of Windows. I guess the problem is in the part of "re-detect the NIC", how to do that ?

Comment: The driver is already there. You just removed the device and Windows will reflect it.

Comment: Okay! So how to re-detect the network interface card ?

Comment: I would hair reboot

Comment: Hair reboot? What's that?

Comment: Autocorrect as its finest. Just reboot.

Comment: Sorry for such a lot of questions, you mean Startup Settings?

Comment: Or to redetect the NIC from BIOS ?

Answer (score 0):

I seen a case where it worked after

- unlocking a secured HDD partition on that computer
- and also finishing the windows updates that were pending.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete this Registy entry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{3d09c1ca-2bcc-40b7-b9bb-3f3ec143a87b}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me
You have to delete this Registy entry

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{3d09c1ca-2bcc-40b7-b9bb-3f3ec143a87b}

This registry is for vmnetwork class id. Conflict with others issues. So I backed up and then deleted this reg. After that all my network card is working fine. Earlier I tried many method. Didn't work. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

**Hay, guys!** I was Getting this error {DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN}
is related to **(an unexpected condition occurred. Not all of your requested changes in settings could be made)** when trying to download the Epic Games Launcher. After some investigation, it turned out that the issue was related to DNS, and the **adapter** it was taking the **DNS from WMware**. To resolve this, all you have to do is **delete** it (the VM), and it will ***run correctly.***

[Note: After deleting the VM, set a static DNS from the TCP/IPv4 settings with **`DNS=8.8.8.8 and alternative DNS=8.8.4.8.]`**

**and if it is not work do this below**

1)Press Win + R to open the Run dialog.

2)Type `regedit` and press Enter to open the Registry Editor.

3)Navigate to the specified registry key:

```
{HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{3d09c1ca-2bcc-40b7-b9bb-3f3ec143a87b}.
```

4)Right-click on the `{3d09c1ca-2bcc-40b7-b9bb-3f3ec143a87b}` key

5)Select "Delete" from the context menu.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I recently faced this issue. This happened to me after uninstalling vmware program. After completing uninstall, I skipped the restart popup and clicked later. I tried some solutions from different forum and end up destroying the WIFI discovery itself.

**Lastly, I reinstalled the vmware program and than wala! the WIFI came back and the "Can't change TCP/IPv4 settings" also solved.**

** I am using windows 11. Please improve this answer if anyone understand why this happened.